# How to compile and run java files for OpenNI in linux

Tags: java, linux, kinect, openni

I'm trying out OpenNI for Kinect and got it to install and run sample code according to 
[this guide](http://mopred.blogspot.com/2011/11/openni-and-nite-on-ubuntu-1110.html). But now, I want to modify the code and compile it and test it. However, I'm not sure how to compile and run on Linux. I found a guide [here](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui13/index.html) that does it for Windows, but can't seem for the life of me to find anything for Linux.

I did try adapting the Windows code for Linux and tried

```
javac -cp ~/kinect/OpenNI/Samples/Bin/x86-Release/org.OpenNI.jar VersionInfo.java
java -cp ~/kinect/OpenNI/Samples/Bin/x86-Release/org.OpenNI.jar VersionInfo
```

but it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: VersionInfo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VersionInfo
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: VersionInfo. Program will exit.
```

Any ideas on how I can compile and run my java code onto the Kinect? If you know how to do it for the Samples in the OpenNI folder, that would be perfect.

Comment: You have compiled your program, since the `javac`command did not complain. But you do change the class path for the JVM when you try to run it. What happens if you remove the `-cp` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out. Turns out I needed to learn about `make` and `Makefile`s and how they're used to compile `.java` files into a `.jar`.